# I want the user to be able to select values only from the drop down and not able to type in the time field

Tags: html, user-interface, time

I am able to restrict user by typing in minutes field with:

```
<input type='time' step="3600" />
```

But not able to restrict from typing in hours (HH:mm).
Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Use JS to validate input. Or create dropdown to select from pre-defined list

Answer (score 0):

(keydown)="$event.preventDefault()"

this worked for me!